# image.Save lossless quality, in XP, pixelated on Windows7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, encoder

So I've come across a rather odd situation.

I'm using the following to Save a PNG (lossless) image,

```
    public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image image, int quality)
    {
        if ((quality < 0) || (quality > 100))
        {
            string error = string.Format("Jpeg image quality must be between 0 and 100, with 100 being the highest quality.  A value of {0} was specified.", quality);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(error);
        }
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        ImageCodecInfo imgCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/png");
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        image.Save(path, imgCodec, encoderParams);
    }

public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        string lookupKey = mimeType.ToLower();
        ImageCodecInfo foundCodec = null;
        if (Encoders.ContainsKey(lookupKey))
        {
            foundCodec = Encoders[lookupKey];
        }
        return foundCodec;
    }
```

This code works great in XP, the image gets saved lossless, when I zoom in, I see no pixelation whatsoever however, when this same compiled application is ran on a windows7 machine, the saved image looks pixelated.

Is this due to the way I'm saving the image or perhaps something changing with the image save functionality / encoding in windows 7?

Comment: You're probably just zooming in differently.

Comment: No, that's not the case. Please feel free to test this in a Windows XP / Windows 7 Environment.

Comment: Then can you post the two images here?

Comment: Sure thing SLaks, I will grab them now.

Comment: !http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/8172/unledbet.png

Answer (score 3):

Your Win7 image is [anti-aliased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing).
This is good, not bad; it makes the text smoother.

It's controlled by properties in the `Graphics` class.

Comment: Just to be very clear, this isn't affected by the saving process, the image is antialiased during rendering, and the save routine is exactly preserving the image.

Comment: How do you disable this AA functionality in the Graphics class?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint.aspx.  However, you probably shouldn't; anti-aliasing is very nice.